# How to inspect ValidationError raised during Prismatic Schema coercion?

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema

As a result of creating a Schema coercer and then trying to coerce a set of data I get as a result:

```
#schema.utils.ErrorContainer{:error #<ValidationError schema.utils.ValidationError@2abfe6ca>}
```

How do I get an explanation of what the actual validation error is?

Comment: Can you post a minimal code sample somewhere so others can look?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the definition of the `ValidationError` type [here](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema/blob/master/src/cljx/schema/utils.cljx#L68) (since you seem to be using Clojure on the JVM I deleted the `#+cljs` expressions):

```
(deftype ValidationError [schema value expectation-delay fail-explanation])
```

And the definition for the `ErrorContainer` record [here](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema/blob/master/src/cljx/schema/utils.cljx#L110):

```
(defrecord ErrorContainer [error])
```

So to get more information about the error you could just access any of the fields of the inner `ValidationError`:

```
(defn validation-error-details [error]
  (let [values (juxt #(.schema %) 
                     #(.value %)
                     #(.expectation-delay %)
                     #(.fail-explanation %))]
    (->> error :error values)))

;; Usage
(validation-error-details error) ; where error holds the value you posted
```